# How to download image from url in Angular?

Tags: angular, url, download

I have a download button where I want to trigger a download for the selected cover image. This works perfectly when my picture is a byte array, but if it's a url then the download doesn't work. It just opens up a new page with the image in the center. I have been searching for an answer for a while now but nothing I found worked. How can I download an image just from a url?

```
          <a #downloadLink [href]="image"
             [download]="'CoverImage' + '.jpg'"></a>
          <button (click)="downloadLink.click()">
             Download  
          </button>
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable downloading an image from a URL directly through a button click, you'll need to modify your approach slightly. The issue you're facing is that when the href attribute of the anchor `<a>` tag is set to a URL, the browser treats it as a link to navigate to, rather than a file to download. This is why it opens the image in a new page.

To fix this, you need to fetch the image programmatically, create a `Blob` (a file-like object of immutable, raw data), and then trigger the download. Here’s how you can do it:

Modify Your HTML: Keep your button, but you can remove the anchor tag.

```
<button (click)="downloadImage(image)">
  Download  
</button>
```

Add a Download Function in Your Component: This function will handle the downloading logic.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

downloadImage(url: string) {
  this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(blob => {
      // Create a link element
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'CoverImage.jpg'; // Set the download filename

      // Append link to the body, click it, and then remove it
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
  }, error => {
      console.error('Error downloading the image: ', error);
  });
}
```

In this function, fetch is used to retrieve the image from the URL. It then converts the response to a `Blob`. We create an anchor `<a>` element in memory, set its href attribute to a URL representing the Blob, and set the download attribute to the desired filename. Then, we programmatically click the link to trigger the download and finally remove the link from the document.

This approach should work for downloading images from URLs in most modern browsers. Remember that CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policies of the server hosting the image can affect your ability to fetch the image if your application is hosted on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

To make an image downloadable from a URL, convert it to a data URL and set it as the `href` attribute of your anchor element. This helps the browser treat the image as a downloadable file. In Angular, you can do it like this:

```js
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class YourComponent {
  image: string; 

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.image = 'https://example.com/your-image.jpg';
  }

  getDownloadUrl(): SafeUrl {
    const dataUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'; 
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(dataUrl + this.image);
  }
}
```

In your template:

```html
<a #downloadLink [href]="getDownloadUrl()"
   [download]="'CoverImage' + '.jpg'"></a>
<button (click)="downloadLink.click()">
   Download  
</button>
```

Comment: With this code, it doesn't open the picture in a new page anymore. Instead, it tried to download the image, but doesn't succeed. It shows an error message: 'Check internet connection and try again' along with a download icon crossed out. I'm not sure why this would happen.

Comment: The issue might be related to the fact that the browser is not allowing the cross-origin download of the image. If the image is hosted on a different domain than your application, the browser's security restrictions may prevent the download.